# Eclipse NWDS doesn't start

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with my Eclipse NWDS that doesn't start with the error below. On my laptop I have installed jdk 1.8.0_301 and also jre 1.8.0_301 on Windows 10
Have you any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

```
!SESSION 2021-10-27 10:30:38.949 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=@qualifier@
java.version=1.8.0_301
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2021-10-27 10:30:49.648
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the key bindings from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' extension point
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2021-10-27 10:30:49.648
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='com.sap.ide.esr.tools.core.ui', id='com.sap.ide.esr.tools.ui.runchecks'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-27 10:30:49.742
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.<clinit>(Collator.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.initialize(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.internalBasicInitialize(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$26.runWithException(Workbench.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3506)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2316)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:191)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I think the Java update version "301" is the cause of the version > 255 message from ICU. I believe this is fixed in current versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for your reply but I need to work with this version because is linked to SAP NetWeaver

Comment: Then your only other choice is to use an older version of Java 8 with a update of less tha 256 and pressure SAP to update their outdated code. Or maybe a newer Java if the version of Eclipse will run with a newer Java (some old versions won't)

Comment: @greg-449: I checked my old laptop and this version works fine with jdk 1.8.0_291 and jre 1.8.0_291, this sound strange for me

Comment: The current version of that code just treats anything in the Java version that is > 255 as 0, but there may have been different patches in the past. Since it is not clear what version you have I can't say for sure what it might accept.